# `dnscrypt-proxy' package freeze at update, remove or reinstall

Tags: apt, upgrade, dnscrypt-proxy

I'm trying to upgrade packages, every time I ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` process freezes at setting up dnscrypt-proxy:

```
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up dnscrypt-proxy (1.4.0-0~oldconf2+trusty1) ...
```

Then I have to kill `apt-get` , `rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`.

I also tried removing package.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue which resolved by following:

1. `sudo lsof -i` which returned me opened ports like below:

```
COMMAND    PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
smbd       643       root   30u  IPv6  10183      0t0  TCP *:microsoft-ds (LISTEN)
smbd       643       root   31u  IPv6  10184      0t0  TCP *:netbios-ssn (LISTEN)
smbd       643       root   32u  IPv4  10185      0t0  TCP *:microsoft-ds (LISTEN)
smbd       643       root   33u  IPv4  10186      0t0  TCP *:netbios-ssn (LISTEN)
dnscrypt-  816   dnscrypt    8u  IPv4  10712      0t0  UDP localhost:mdns 
dnscrypt-  816   dnscrypt   10u  IPv4  10714      0t0  TCP localhost:mdns (LISTEN)
.
.
.
```

Last two lines say dnscrypt is alive by PID#816

2. `sudo kill 816` killed it.
3. `sudo apt-get remove dnscrypt-proxy` is now free to remove package with no frezze!

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use the Ubuntu packages from my PPA as I usually provide the latest available version :

https://launchpad.net/~anton+/+archive/ubuntu/dnscrypt

Explanations on how to use it are in more recent webupd8 article :

[Encrypt DNS Traffic In Ubuntu With DNSCrypt [Ubuntu PPA]](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/encrypt-dns-traffic-in-ubuntu-with.html)